# TypeError: cartItems.find is not a function

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

**Hello everyone, I can't solve this problem when I try to remove an item but I got this problem TypeError: cartItems.find is not a function**

**Cart.utils.js**

```
export const removeItemFromCart = (cartItems, cartItemToRemove) => {
  const existingCartItem = cartItems.find(
    (cartItem) => cartItem.id === cartItemToRemove.id
  );

  if (existingCartItem.quantity === 1) {
    return cartItems.find((cartItem) => cartItem.id !== cartItemToRemove.id);
  }

  return cartItems.map((cartItem) =>
    cartItem.id === cartItemToRemove.id
      ? { ...cartItem, quantity: cartItem.quantity - 1 }
      : cartItem
  );
};
```

**cart.reducer.js**

```
 case CartActionType.REMOVE_ITEM:
  return {
    ...state,
    cartItems: removeItemFromCart(state.cartItems, action.payload),
  };
```

**checkoutItem.js**

```
      ........

        <span className="left-arrow" onClick={() => removeItem(item)}>
          &#10096;
        </span>
       .......
  );
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  removeItem: (item) => dispatch(removeItemFromCart(item)),
});

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(CheckoutItem);
```

Comment: I can notice an error at `existingCartItem.quantity === 1` condition. you should use `filter` not `find`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@buzzato is right about the source of the problem and the solution.

The error `cartItems.find is not a function` means that at some point `cartItems` is something other than an `array`.  When you dispatch an action to remove an item with quantity `1`, you hit this condition:

```
if (existingCartItem.quantity === 1) {
  return cartItems.find((cartItem) => cartItem.id !== cartItemToRemove.id);
}
```

[`.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) actually returns the first value that matches your condition, not an array of matches.  So after you hit that condition your `state.cartItems` becomes a single object instead of an array.  The next time you try to remove any item, you will will get the error `cartItems.find is not a function` because you are trying to call `.find()` on an object.

You want to use [`.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) instead of `.find()` as `filter()` returns an array of every element that matches your condition.